# StructureMap initialization issue

Tags: c#, structuremap

Currently am using the structure map for injecting the transactionid which is a uniqie Guid that needs to be created each time

```
x.For<ITransaction>()
 .Use<Transaction>()
 .Ctor<string>("transactionId").Is(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
 .Ctor<string>("transactionType").Is(settings["TransactionTypeValue"]);
```

With in controller ITransaction is passed as an argument and getting the TransactionId .
But am not getting the unique Guid whenever the action method is invoked .
Its all set while loading the application and the same value is coming up every time.
How can i generate unique Guid each time when the action method is getting called using the structure map configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are just setting the value to be the same when you initialise your container. try setting to be a function that returns a GUID, like this:

```
x.For<ITransaction>()
.Use<Transaction>()
.Ctor<string>("transactionId").Is(() => Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
.Ctor<string>("transactionType").Is(settings["TransactionTypeValue"]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. worked like a charm.Please could you tell me what this function is doing .Is(() => Guid.NewGuid()

Comment: @Jammy123 When you set the values, the function is only executed once (when you initialise your container, usually during app start up), so GUID.NewGuid is only ever called once. Instead of passing in a value directly, there is an overload to `.Is` that allows you to pass in a function that returns a variable of the right type instead. That function is then called every time you get an instance of x.

Comment: Is there any way we can implement the same using the structuremap version 2.6.4.0.Because this overload for .Is(() => Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) is not available in the previous version.Any alternative for this ? .The client application is using the older version of structure map so i wont be able to update the version since it require lot of changes in entire app.@Anduril Please could you help me out here...

Comment: @Jammy123 Hi Jammy, sorry for the delay, haven't been on in a few days. I'm not too familiar with that version of structure map, and I'm having trouble finding the docs. If have a link to them I can have a look, but off the top of my head I don't know